# Start Chrome by command line, but adding some arguments to make it login into your Google account automatically

Tags: linux, google-chrome, shell-script

Is there a way to start Chrome calling it from the command line (using Linux), but providing it some argument to make it login into some Google account automatically?  I'm looking for something like `google-chrome -account foo -pass bar` that I can easily put in a bash script later.

A little background: I have a laptop connected to my TV, which is currently using just a mouse for user interaction. There's no google account logged in by default, and that's the way I want to keep it, so my kids can't come across videos and pictures in google and youtube that they are not supposed to see (e.g.: adult content, or anything marked as not appropriate for kids by the google's safe search filters).  The bad thing about this is that there are some music videos in youtube that requires you to be logged in to see, usually those we (the adults) used to sing when playing karaoke... as the only input available is a mouse, I'm looking for a way to start with my google account without having to type the whole thing usin the on-screen keyboard.

You may think "*Why you can't use the keyboard, if the laptop is right there?*".   Well, it's in a kind of uncomfortable position - too high for me without a chair or something, as it's right above the furniture in where the TV is located.

Is there a way to make this scriptable?  If not, do you know any other workaround?

Note: using the *remember me after logging off* or alike options are discarded, as the  *safe-search* chrome version must be always the default version to run.

Comment: You could use something like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) maybe?

Comment: Since you're automating a web browser, I guess [Selenium could be used here](http://www.pushtotest.com/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners-tutorial-1) even though I don't think it was actually intended to be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install lastpass extension, add site/account, choose auto-login when adding the site.
Start chome from command line

```
google-chorme <URL>
```

It should log you in.